# Fix horizontal scrollbar for internet explorer 7 browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I don't know why the horizontal scroll appears for this site in `ie7`.

 
This works very well in all other browsers. 
Not able to figure why exactly this happens.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

http://d9692994.u118.c6.ixwebhosting.com/vishal-enterprise/website/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing jquery library. check your console errors. you need to call jquery library before all js file.

Try this in your css:

```
html{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
body{
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Well, you should still fix the js errors in console...lemme take a look.

Comment: I have uploaded the js, but still it has no result

Comment: Try this overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;...answer editted

Comment: Add html{overflow-x: hidden;} along with the above. check answer again

Comment: The above works ...I tested in IE7...try again and let us know

Answer (score 0):

What about adding some style to your `body`?

```
body {
     overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I haven't tested yet but this should work.